What are μ,~ in the testing logs for foundry
While testing the smart contracts on Foundry I am getting this log
(runs: 256, μ: 31132, ~: 31288)

I want to know the exact meaning of the μ, and ~ symbol.
The full log
➜  foundry_fund_me git:(master) forge test
[⠊] Compiling...
[⠔] Compiling 25 files with Solc 0.8.18
[⠒] Solc 0.8.18 finished in 3.38s
Compiler run successful!

Ran 2 tests for test/Counter.t.sol:CounterTest
[PASS] testFuzz_SetNumber(uint256) (runs: 256, μ: 31132, ~: 31288)
[PASS] test_Increment() (gas: 31303)
Suite result: ok. 2 passed; 0 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 28.35ms (30.67ms CPU time)

Ran 1 test suite in 66.44ms (28.35ms CPU time): 2 tests passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped (2 total tests)

I have written a simple test and a basic contract.


μ (mu): represents the average gas usage across the fuzz test runs.
In your example:
μ: 31132

This means that the average gas consumption for the fuzzing test testFuzz_SetNumber(uint256) was 31,132 units of gas.

~ (tilde): represents the median gas usage across the fuzz test runs.
In your example:
~: 31288

This means that the median gas consumption for the test was 31,288 units of gas.



I hope that you’re already aware of runs. It indicates how many test iterations (random inputs) were executed during fuzzing. In your case:
runs: 256

This means 256 different inputs were tested for the testFuzz_SetNumber(uint256) function.

Thanks for clearing it out

You’re welcome!
